# How to use ConstraintLayout in compose multiplatform for desk

Tags: android-constraintlayout, compose-multiplatform

build.gradle.kts

[image]

I tried to add this dependency

[image]

I want to use ConstraintLayput in compose multiplatform for desk, but I don't know how to correctly add the dependency of compose's ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

Please change your dependency with:

```
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")
```

and use the `linkTo()` method of constraint